# Get the value of the selected radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have defined a set of radio buttons in HTML in a form as follows. The name of my form is "MyForm". When Female is selected, I want the value of a variable to be equal to "Female".

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="gender" name="gender">
                    <legend>Gender :</legend>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked" />
                        <label for="radio-choice-1">Male</label>

 <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2"/>
                        <label for="radio-choice-2">Female</label>
                </fieldset>
```

I tried as var

```
genderValue = $('input[name=gender]:checked', '#MyForm').val()
```

But this is not working. What is the correct way?

Comment: var selected ='checked="checked"';
var e = document.getElementById("state");
var state_selected = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
Try this out

Comment: Why not just have `<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" />` `<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" />`

Comment: I am not sure why you are using $('input[name=gender], You should use $('input[name=radio-choice-1]:checked'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can store the values(`female`,`...`), in value attribute of the inputs, based on your markup you can try the following:

```
$('input[name="radio-choice-1"]').change(function(){
   var genderValue = $(this).next('label').text()
})
```

---

but I'd suggest this one:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="gender" name="gender">
   <legend>Gender :</legend>
   <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="Male" checked="checked" />
   <label for="radio-choice-1">Male</label>
   <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="Female"/>
   <label for="radio-choice-2">Female</label>
</fieldset>
```

```
$('input[name="radio-choice-1"]').change(function(){
   var genderValue = this.value
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue has been solved as below:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="MyForm" name="MyForm" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>
      Gender
    </legend>
    <div id="panel">
      <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" />
      <label for="radio-choice-1">
        Male
      </label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2" />
      <label for="radio-choice-2">
        Female
      </label>
    </div>
    <div id="result">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="radio-choice"]').change(function() {
        var genderValue = $(this).next('label').text();
        $("#result").html("<p> You have selected " + genderValue + ".");
    })
});
```

I have done bins on http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqpaa

Answer (score 1):

This might helpful to someone, Here is another way to retrieve selected radio button value

```
var gender = $('input[name="radio-choice-1"]:checked').val();
```

Setting id to radio buttons is optional here.

Happy coding!....